# stringr::str_replace I want to change the days of the week, for example Monday, Tuesday

Tags: r, stringr

In my data frame table, the days of the week are integer type. I want to change the days of the week, for example Monday, Tuesday.

I tried `stringr::str_replace()`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample data using `dput(x)` refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Please try to capture sample data and desired output next time. I will try based on provided info.

1. Simple Approach :
   Lets say your data has a column weekday with integer values, similar to this- added data just for sample:

   ```
   df <- data.frame(
      days_n =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
      ,SomeData = c('A','AA','BB','CC','BB','AAA','CCC'))
   ```

Then just mutate using wonderful `lubridate`

```
df%>%mutate(Weekday = wday(x = days_n,label = T,abbr = T))
```

will give you :

```
 days_n SomeData Weekday
1      1        A     Sun
2      2       AA     Mon
3      3       BB     Tue
4      4       CC     Wed
5      5       BB     Thu
6      6      AAA     Fri
7      7      CCC     Sat
```

Check `wday()` in `lubridate` for more.

Comment: If this helped, please accept and close. Thanks